# Rectangular Array with macro

Tags: vba

I've tried to create an array with 2 row and 5 columns in VBA codes. Is it possible? i wrote like this

Sub robin()

```
Cells.Select                    'this codes clears previous entries
Range("T17").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E4").Select

Dim myArray(1, 4) As Double
Dim a As Double, b As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer 
Dim c As Double
c = 1

For a = 0 To UBound(myArray())
    For b = 0 To UBound(myArray())
        myArray(a, b) = c
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 1, b + 1).Value = myArray(a, b)

        c = c + 1
    Next b

Next a
```

End Sub

But it comes with two rows and two columns. What to do?

Comment: vba 2d are dont work exactly like in other languages. please note that you shoud get the array lenths this way:http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/245779-ubound-multi-dimensional-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

By default UBound will return the highest index of the first dimension of an array.  You'll need to set the optional parameter to 2 to get the last index of the 2nd dimension.

```
 For b = 0 To UBound(myArray(), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub batman()
    [Sheet1!A1:E2] = [{1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10}]
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub robin()
    Dim myArray(1 To 2, 1 To 5) As Double, c As Long

    For c = 1 To 5
        myArray(1, c) = c
        myArray(2, c) = c + 5
    Next

    [Sheet1!A1:E2] = myArray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you for your time. I've figured out my way to get what I was looking for. I rewrote the code like this:

Sub robin()

```
Cells.Select                    'this codes clears previous entries
Range("T17").Activate
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E4").Select

Dim myArray(1, 5) As Double
Dim a As Double, b As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim c As Double
c = 1

For a = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
    For b = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 2)
        myArray(a, b) = c
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 1, b + 1).Value = myArray(a, b)

        c = c + 1
    Next b


Next a
```

End Sub

And that worked perfect for me. Thanks again.